# probability question test

Tags: probability, statistics

This a question i had on my test.

$2\%$ of cats, $65\%$ of dogs and $0.05\%$ of snakes are over $40$ pounds in a town.

A) What is the probability of picking an animal over $40$ pounds from $80$ cats, $15$ dogs and $2000$ snakes.

My thoughts:

i had no idea how to solve this but this is what i did:

each percentage $\times$ each corresponding animal # $(80,15,2000)$ and all that divided by the total number of possible animals.

Answer (score 2):

Note that intuitively,
$$
\mathbb{P}[\text{big animal}] = \frac{\text{# big animals}}{\text{# animals}}
  = \frac{0.02 \cdot 80 + 0.65 \cdot 15 + 0.05 \cdot 2000}{80+15+2000}
  = \frac{111.35}{2095} \approx 5.315 \%
$$

Answer (score 1):

It looks from your description as if you did the problem correctly.

We assume we choose one of the $2095$ animals, with any of the animals equally likely to be chosen. A perhaps unreasonable assumption, I would prefer to avoid the snakes.

If you pick an animal at random in the above sense, then with probability $\frac{80}{2095}$ it is a cat, with corresponding probabilities for the other kinds of animal.

**Given** that the animal is a cat, the probability the animal is over $40$ pounds is $0.02$. So the probability you pick a cat **and** the cat is over $40$ pounds if $\left(\frac{80}{2095}\right)(0.02)$. Do the same for the others and add.